# how to get past n interations of workitems from azure devops rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-workitem, wiql

I need to pull the current iterations and past n iterations of workitems with specific fields dynamically.

To explain you in detail about Past n iterations.
Lets say my n is 5, then i would need workitems from current iteration, past iteration to current iteration and past to past to current iteration.

In total i have more than 400 iterations out of which i will need to pull latest past 5 iteration workitems.

To fetch the workitems with specific fields from current iteration, this is the powershell script i have written

```
$token = 'your PAT'
$url="https://dev.azure.com/Organizationname/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$JSON = @'
{
   "query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType],  [System.State],[System.AreaPath],[System.Tags],[System.CommentCount],[System.ChangedDate] 
                   FROM workitems 
              Where [System.AreaPath] = 'area path' 
                 and [System.IterationPath] = 'iteration path' 
                 and [System.WorkItemType] = 'Story' 
              order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
'@
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
$listOfTasks = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
ForEach( $workitem in $response.workItems ) {
  $listOfTasks.Add($workitem.id)
}
$listOfTasks = $listOfTasks -join ','
$listOfTasks
$JSON1 = @"
{
  
  "ids": [$listOfTasks],
  "fields": [
    "System.Id",
    "System.Title",
    "System.WorkItemType",
    "System.IterationPath",
  ]      
}
"@
$JSON1
$url1="https://dev.azure.com/Organizationname/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=5.0"
$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON1 -ContentType application/json
Write-Host "result = $($response1 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Can someone please help me in tweaking this logic, so that i can get current and past n iterations workitems.
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Past and current iterations are in the team settings. So, you have to know the team name to get the iteration list. Then:

1. In the team settings you can get iterations: [Iterations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.1-preview.1`

2. Each iteration contains dates and the timeframe (current, future, past).
3. You can use an iteration from the list in your source code or use [Iterations - Get Iteration Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/get%20iteration%20work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get iteration work items:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/workitems?api-version=6.1-preview.1`

Example to get last 5 past iteration:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<PAT>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$org = "<ORG_NAME>"
$teamProject = "<PROJECT_NAME>"
$teamName = "<TEAM_NAME>"

$restApiGetIterations = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$teamProject/$teamName/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=6.1-preview.1"

$restApiGetIterations

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{   
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
}


$iterations = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetIterations

$pastIterations = $iterations.value | Where-Object {$_.attributes.timeFrame -eq "past"} 

$past5Iterations = $pastIterations | Sort-Object -Property {$_.attributes.finishDate} | Select-Object -Last 5


$past5Iterations
```

Comment: Yes, I do know this. But what I want is I need to fetch last 5 iterations of work items only, but  not everything that’s available. And for all of the past iterations the value assigned for timeframe is past, in my case there are more than 400 past iterations out of which I want only latest 5 past iterations work items :-(

Comment: @Jennie, so you have to get only 5 last iterations from your 400 iterations. I`ve updated my answer.

Comment: wow !!! its working like a pro. one small question!! what If i need to get the current iteration details with the past 5 iteratson details.

Comment: I was able to get the current iteration information too. Thank you very much for the wonderful script.